# How to configure oracle thin connectionpool in glassfish server?

Tags: java

Not able to create working oraclethin connection pool in glass-fish server,i'm using oracle 10g xe and i'm trying to create connection pool using ojdbc14.jar but i'm not successful so far so please!

Answer (score 1):

before you start your glass fish server **place the ojbc14.jar** in glassfish-3.1.1\glassfish3\glassfish\domains\domain1\lib\ext

step 1: In common task panel (left side of glass fish console) you'll find JDBC. under JDBC you'll find JDBC resource and JDBC connection Pool. **click on JDBC Connection pool.**

step 2: enter the pool name, resource type and databae vendor type then click next. refer the screenshot.

step 3:in this page, don't modify any fields in general setting **except ping checkbox**. **In additional property section , give the user name, password , and connection url.** The default url for oracle 10g is jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe.

click on save.if properly completed oracle 10G installation, you will be able to ping the JDBC connection pool.

step 4: to create a JNDI look up name , goto JDBC->JDBC resource->new then create JNDI look up name and click on pool name whick you created in step 1. click save. that's all.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and the solutions was to put ojdbc*.jar to the

```
glassfish-3.1.1\glassfish3\glassfish\domains\domain1\lib\ext
```

directory, the restart GF, then configure pool.